# How to perform JOIN operation and to remove duplicate rows, using PHP + MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like below:

**table-a**

[image: tablea]

**table-b**

[image: tableb]

The color code shows how the entries of table are related. table-a shows item name and it's constituent tags (let it be the ids of it's ingredients / components). Table-b shows the form in which the item is available, say, item `1111` is available in cup, item `2222` in both cone and bar etc. What I need is, when I give `tagid`, I want to retrieve corresponding `type`s in which it is available.

If it give `101,102`, it should return;

```
cup
```

If it give `101,103`, it should return;

```
cone
bar
cup
```

In the second case, note that it actually returns

```
cone
bar
cone
cup
```

But I don't want `cone` to be repeated. I don't want duplicate rows.

How can I do this? Is this some kind of `JOIN` operation? I use PHP+MySQL. Is this possible with MySQL alone / with the help of PHP?

Comment: YOU CAN USE GROUP BY OF PARTICULAR ID

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT is the way to go. (Why group by when no aggregate functions are involved...?)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL query example:

```
select distinct type
from tableb b inner join tablea a on b.product = a.item
where a.tagid IN (101,103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tableb.type 
FROM tableb INNER JOIN tablea ON tablea.item = tableb.product
WHERE tablea.tagid IN ('YOUR-IDS-ARRAY')
GROUP BY tableb.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select type from tableb b inner join tablea a on b.product = a.item where a.tagid IN (101,103) group by type
```